# How to interpret rank-biserial correlation coefficients for Wilcoxon test?

Tags: correlation, nonparametric, effect-size, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I know that Pearson's $r$ correlation coefficient can be classified as follows [(Wikipedia entry)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effect_size):

- small size if $r \in [0.1, 0.3)$,
- medium size if $r \in [0.3, 0.5)$
- large size if $r \in [0.5, 1]$

I've read somewhere that we can calculate the rank-biserial correlation coefficient as $r = W / S$ in Wilcoxon signed-rank test ($S$ is the sum of ranks). My question is are there standard values to classify this effect size as small, medium etc, like those for Pearson's $r$?

Comment: In some fields the researcher would be over the moon to get an r as high as 0.3 whereas in other fields they would be deeply disappointed to get one as low as 0.9.

Comment: The link to "this article" is broken.

Comment: @amoeba, thanks for the notification. Since I did not remember which article was in question so that I can write its title now, I will remove the link.

Comment: Did you notice that those characterizations of $r$ are specifically for the *social sciences*?  Thus, not only is @mdewey challenging the overly general characterization that forms the basis of this question, it's not even supported by your reference!

Comment: No, I did not notice that those thresholds for $r$ were specific for social sciences, and thought that there was a general characterization of the values of $r$ for Wilcoxon signed-rank test, applicable in all the fields. Only when @mdewey pointed out that interpretation is field-specific, did I become aware of that fact.